# Nested function crashing the Swift compiler

Tags: swift, generics, nested, mergesort, nested-generics

I wrote a recursive `mergeSort` function:

```
func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(inout array: [T]) {
    if array.count <= 1 {
        return
    }

    var leftSlice = [T](array[0..<array.count / 2])
    var rightSlice = [T](array[array.count / 2...array.endIndex - 1])

    mergeSort(&leftSlice)
    mergeSort(&rightSlice)
    array = merge(leftSlice, rightSlice)
}

func merge<T: Comparable>(var left: [T], var right: [T]) -> [T] {
    var mergedValues = [T]()

    while !left.isEmpty && !right.isEmpty {
        mergedValues.append(left.first! < right.first! ? left.removeAtIndex(0) : right.removeAtIndex(0))
    }

    if !left.isEmpty {
        mergedValues += left
    } else if !right.isEmpty {
        mergedValues += right
    }

    return mergedValues
}
```

Now, since `merge()` is only supposed to be used by `mergeSort()` I placed it inside of `mergeSort()`, therefore making `merge()` a [nested function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158):

```
func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(inout array: [T]) {
    func merge<T: Comparable>(var left: [T], var right: [T]) -> [T] {
        var mergedValues = [T]()

        while !left.isEmpty && !right.isEmpty {
            mergedValues.append(left.first! < right.first! ? left.removeAtIndex(0) : right.removeAtIndex(0))
        }

        if !left.isEmpty {
            mergedValues += left
        } else if !right.isEmpty {
            mergedValues += right
        }

        return mergedValues
    }

    if array.count <= 1 {
        return
    }

    var leftSlice = [T](array[0..<array.count / 2])
    var rightSlice = [T](array[array.count / 2...array.endIndex - 1])

    mergeSort(&leftSlice)
    mergeSort(&rightSlice)
    array = merge(leftSlice, rightSlice)
}
```

Now the [first](http://swiftstub.com/692375358/) version works fine, but the [second](http://swiftstub.com/426295707/) one doesn't.
How can that be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in the compiler related to nested generic functions.  Here's a reduction that also crashes the 1.2 compiler:

```
func f<T>(t: T) {
    func g<U>(u: U) { }
}
```

But in this case, you don't actually need a generic version of `merge`.  Its generic parameter is the same as the outer function, therefore just use that:

```
func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(inout array: [T]) {
    // no generic placeholder needed, T is the T for mergeSort
    func merge(var left: [T], var right: [T]) -> [T] {
      // etc.
    }
}
```

This appears to work fine.

However, it's also worth pointing out that in your `merge` function, you're calling `removeAtIndex` in a loop, which is a *O(n)* function.  This means your merge sort is not going to have the hoped-for complexity.

Here's an alternative version to consider:

```
func mergeSort<T: Comparable>(inout array: [T], range: Range<Int>? = nil) {

    func merge(left: Range<Int>, right: Range<Int>) -> [T] {    
        var tmp: [T] = []
        tmp.reserveCapacity(count(left) + count(right))

        var l = left.startIndex, r = right.startIndex

        while l != left.endIndex && r != right.endIndex {
            if array[l] < array[r] {
                tmp.append(array[l++])
            }
            else {
                tmp.append(array[r++])
            }
        }
        // where left or right may be empty, this is a no-op
        tmp += source[l..<left.endIndex]
        tmp += source[r..<right.endIndex]

        return tmp
    }

    // this allows the original caller to omit the range,
    // the default being the full array
    let r = range ?? indices(array)
    if count(r) > 1 {
        let mid = r.startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex.distanceTo(r.endIndex)/2)
        let left = r.startIndex..<mid
        let right = mid..<r.endIndex

        mergeSort(&array, range: left)
        mergeSort(&array, range: right)
        let merged = merge(left, right)
        array.replaceRange(r, with: merged)
    }
}
```

I'd also say that since `merge` is probably a generically useful function in its own right, you may as well make it stand-alone rather than nesting it (similarly, `partition` when implementing a quick sort). The nesting doesn't buy you anything (outside of the trick I used above of referencing the outer parameter from within it, which is probably a bad practice anyway, I mostly did it to show you can :)

Comment: I noticed this too. Playground won't even run if I introduce a nested generic, and trying to compile with nested generics yields a segmentation fault.

Comment: yes, it's a compiler crash rather than a runtime error (I've edited the question title)

Comment: Ok, I have a few Questions:
(1) How did you know that `removeAtIndex` takes *O(n)* time? ||  
(2) Is it possible to create static arrays without initializing them, by somehow using `reserveCapacity` on arrays defined with `let`? ||
(3) Why do you know so much about Swift?

Comment: (1) easy answer: it's in the docs :) hover your mouse over `removeAtIndex` and you'll see the info.  But also, it's intuitive given arrays declared in Swift are a contiguous lump of memory – all the subsequent elements need to shuffle down to fill the gap. In fact removing the first element is the _worst case_ for this since this means maximum shuffling.  (2) no there isn't but think about why that wouldn't make sense – `let` declares an immutable value, and arrays are value types so if declared with `let` they can never be added to – so why reserve additional space?  (3) experimenting!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make `merge` a generic function. Generic `T` is already defined for `mergeSort` so you just set `[T]` as your parameter in the inner function:

```
func merge(var left: [T], var right: [T]) -> [T] {
    var mergedValues = [T]()
    ...
}
```